# 'bool' object is not callable - TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, dataset, data-science, python-3.7

i was trying to apply the following code ( i am using the imdb review dataset )

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer 

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents = None,
                       lowercase = False,preprocessor = False,
                       tokenizer = tokenizer_porter,
                       use_idf = True, 
                       norm = 'l2',
                       smooth_idf = True)

y = data.sentiment.values
x = tfidf.fit_transform(data.review)
```

and i got this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-d080ac7d83fe> in <module>
      9 
     10 y = data.sentiment.values
---> 11 x = tfidf.fit_transform(data.review)
```

.
.
.

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

please help ! thanx in advance :3

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `False` to the `preprocessor` argument, which can only be `None` or a callable object.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> **preprocessor: callable or None (default=None)**
>
> Override the preprocessing (string transformation) stage while
>   preserving the tokenizing and n-grams generation steps. Only applies
>   if analyzer is not callable.

Comment: @ShahidNagra - was there any problem with the answer that made you unaccept it?